# Explicit form of the Poincare-AdS$_3$ geometry

Tags: anti-de-sitter-spacetime

The Poincare-AdS$_3$ geometry is given in the Wikipedia article on [Anti-de Sitter space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space) as

$$ds^{2} = \frac{dr^{2}}{r^{2}} + r^{2}g_{\alpha\beta}dx^{\alpha}dx^{\beta}$$

$$=\frac{dr^{2}}{r^{2}} + r^{2}(-dt^{2} + dx^{2}),$$

where $(t,x)$ are the coordinates on the boundary of the cylinder. Therefore, using $x = r \theta$, we find that

$$ds^{2} = \frac{dr^{2}}{r^{2}} - r^{2}dt^{2} + r^{4}d\theta^{2}.$$

But I am not able to make a consistent dimensional analysis. For example, $dr^{2}/r^{2}$ is dimensionless, but $r^{2}dt^{2}$ has a mass dimension of $-4$ and $r^{4}d\theta^{2}$ also has a mass dimension of $-4$.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What dimension do you expect for $\mathrm{d}s^2$, and why?

Comment: I expect $ds^{2}$ to have a mass dimension of $-2$ because it is a length squared.

Comment: Have you checked about restoring factors of $c$ and $\hbar$?